# Replace multiple objects conditionally

Tags: python

I have a problem with the symbols ^ and .

I need to replace all \ and ^ with \ and \^. But we don't know which ones are present in the search string containing it .

The combination can be in any order .

```
if '\\'or '^' in Pattern:
         Pattern = Pattern.replace("\\",r"\\")
```

Now i need to replace \ , ^ or both .Whichever is found . 
If both are present , then both . Or if any one of them is found , then that one.

How do we replace conditionally , one , or all ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace without testing:

```
Pattern = Pattern.replace("\\",r"\\").replace("^",r"\^")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'\\'or '^' in Pattern
```

is the logical OR of the expressions

```
'\\'
```

and

```
'^' in Pattern
```

the first of which is always true.

If you want to look for either one of these characters in a string, do

```
'\\' in Pattern or '^' in Pattern
```

Comment: HI Again , if anybody following this , can someone explain me how this is happening?

'>>> a='abc''
'>>> print 'd' or 'e' in a'
'd'
'>>> print 'd' in a or 'a' in a'
'True'
'>>> print any(c in a for c in 'da')'
'True'

Comment: @arindamroychowdhury: please don't post new questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then I presume you're trying to do something like:

`Pattern = Pattern.replace("\",r"\\").replace("^",r"\^")`

*(looks like someone has already answered this question while I was typing)*